# Accessing a global varibile in any class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Hey all i have been trying to figure out why i am getting this warning:

> 'TxtAppDelegate' may not respond to '-TCN'
>   'TxtAppDelegate' may not respond to '-TID'

when i try to use this code:

```
// .h file
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
NSString *theCompanyName;
NSString *theID;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *theCompanyName;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *theID;

// .m
NSString *theCompanyName;
NSString *theID;

@synthesize theCompanyName;
@synthesize theID;

TxtAppDelegate *customObjInstance = [[TxtAppDelegate alloc] init];

theCompanyName = [customObjInstance TCN];
theID = [customObjInstance TID];
```

I've added the header for the .h file that has the two functions in them. The code works but i really would like to solve the warning problem.

Any help would be great to solve this problem of mine :)

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it would have been more helpful to see the header file where TxtAppDelegate is declared, I'm guessing the method declarations must be off. They should look like this:

```
- (NSString *)TCN;
- (NSString *)TID;
```

If this is not the cause of the problem, please post the header file here so we can examine it.

Answer (score 0):

How are declared these two functions in your header?

They should belong to a category of `TxtAppDelegate` class or to a protocol. If you choose the protocol, `TxtAppDelegate` interface should mention that it conforms to that protocol.